# what is the meaning of "scene-based UI" concept in iOS

Tags: ios, ios13

I am a Xamarin.Forms developer and recently I started training on native iOS development. Throught the reading of Apple's documentation I faced many times "Scene-based UI" or "Scene-based application" concept, and I could not find out what is it. I made some searches on google but I could not feel I understand what is it excactly. So, can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 13 introduced a new app architecture where, instead of just a window, there is a UIWindowScene that owns the window. Among other things, this allows iPad apps to have more than one window, but this architecture is present even if the app has just the one window.